# Parse nested XML in Dart / Flutter

Tags: xml, flutter, dart, xml-parsing

I need help parsing a nested XML file in Dart/Flutter.

I have a Dart class

```
class Genre {
String id;
String title;
String token;
String type;
// For children objets I want to get list of IDs
// as String
List<String> subGenres;
}
```

The XML file looks as follow:

```
<genres>
  <genre id="5003" title="Бизнес-книги" type="root">
    <genre id="5049" title="Банковское дело" token="bankovskoe_delo" type="genre"/>
    <genre id="5047" title="Кадровый менеджмент" token="kadrovyj_menedzhment" type="container">
      <genre id="5334" title="Аттестация персонала" token="attestaciya_personala" type="genre"/>
      <genre id="5330" title="Гендерные различия" token="gendernyye_razlichiya" type="genre"/>
      <genre id="5332" title="Конфликты" token="konflikty" type="genre"/>
    </genre>
  </genre>
  <genre id="5013" title="Юмористическая литература" type="root">
    <genre id="5201" title="Анекдоты" token="anekdoty" type="genre"/>
    <genre id="5202" title="Зарубежный юмор" token="zarubezhnyy" type="genre"/>
  </genre>
</genres>
```

So I have maybe unlimited levels of sub-genres.
If a type of object is 'root' or 'container' it contains sub-genres, type 'genre' is a single record (like folders and files).

How can I get the list of all of my objects and parse it to class objects ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `xml` package. I like to use a factory constructor that takes an `XmlElement`. There's no reason to limit yourself to a `List<String>` for the children; you could have a `List<Genre>` to build a tree that mirrors your XML. (You could, of course, do that instead if you prefer.)

Notice how the factory constructor iterates through any child XML elements, recursively calling itself. The `normal` constructor is private, so that only the factory constructor uses it. If a genre has no sub-genres, the `subGenres` list `isEmpty`.

```
import 'package:xml/xml.dart';

var sample = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<genres>
  <genre id="5003" title="Бизнес-книги" type="root">
    <genre id="5049" title="Банковское дело" token="bankovskoe_delo" type="genre"/>
    <genre id="5047" title="Кадровый менеджмент" token="kadrovyj_menedzhment" type="container">
      <genre id="5334" title="Аттестация персонала" token="attestaciya_personala" type="genre"/>
      <genre id="5330" title="Гендерные различия" token="gendernyye_razlichiya" type="genre"/>
      <genre id="5332" title="Конфликты" token="konflikty" type="genre"/>
    </genre>
  </genre>
  <genre id="5013" title="Юмористическая литература" type="root">
    <genre id="5201" title="Анекдоты" token="anekdoty" type="genre"/>
    <genre id="5202" title="Зарубежный юмор" token="zarubezhnyy" type="genre"/>
  </genre>
</genres>
''';

class Genre {
  Genre._(this.id, this.title, this.token, this.type, this.subGenres);

  factory Genre.fromElement(XmlElement genreElement) {
    return Genre._(
      genreElement.getAttribute('id'),
      genreElement.getAttribute('title'),
      genreElement.getAttribute('token'),
      genreElement.getAttribute('type'),
      genreElement
          .findElements('genre')
          .map<Genre>((e) => Genre.fromElement(e))
          .toList(),
    );
  }

  String id;
  String title;
  String token;
  String type;
  List<Genre> subGenres;
}

void main() {
  var root = XmlDocument.parse(sample).getElement('genres');
  var rootGenres = root
      .findElements('genre')
      .map<Genre>((e) => Genre.fromElement(e))
      .toList();

  print(rootGenres);
}
```

Comment: Thank you man, you saved my day. Now I need to realize how to put this stuff to firebase an to show it in ListViews )). I think I'll put all the genres to the top level and address the children genres by ids list in parent genre.

Comment: Thank you again. I've almost completely finished my production code w/ your help. How can I accept the answer in stack ? And I have another question on flutter xml package, if you can help it'll be cool - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63431246/parse-a-huge-xml-in-dart-flutter